# Calling sproc on SQL Azure from Invoke-Sqlcmd

Tags: azure-sql-database

The form to hit a regular sql server:

```
$server = "192.168.1.1"
$myDatabase = "Adventures"
$myUser = "Joe"
$myPass = "BadPass"

Invoke-Sqlcmd  -ServerInstance $server -Database $myDatabase -Username $myUser -Password $myPass
```

For Azure SQL http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-azure/ tells me to bracket the servername as:

> [plkahglkhjl].database.windows.net

but that gets me a error message that the server can not be found or was not accessible. It's behaving as if it were a firewall blocking but I have a open connection in SSMS without problem.

Is there another set of validation/authentication that PowerShell scripts have to deal with?

thx

Comment: Can you post the exact text of the error or post a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

ConnectionStrings.com is just indicating that you need to replace those fields with your own, not that you actually need brackets.

1) You **do not** need to bracket your server name

`plkahglkhjl.database.windows.net`

2) You **do** need to put the server name in the UserName

`Joe@plkahglkhjl`

More details here: [Error connecting to SQL Azure Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926195/error-connection-with-azure-sql-database-with-windows-azure/16942737#16942737)

Comment: Thanks - but still the same problem. From an asp.net where conventional connection strings are used - stuff works. Attempting to code it into the form required by a PowerShell script is the problem.

Comment: Point #2 no longer is true: you don't need the `@servername` in the username. Possibly you did in a previous version of Azure SQL DB but not any more.